# Depth-first search (DFS) code in python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

Can you please let me know what is incorrect in below DFS code. It's giving correct result AFAIK, but I don't know when it will fail.

```
graph1 = {
    'A' : ['B','S'],
    'B' : ['A'],
    'C' : ['D','E','F','S'],
    'D' : ['C'],
    'E' : ['C','H'],
    'F' : ['C','G'],
    'G' : ['F','S'],
    'H' : ['E','G'],
    'S' : ['A','C','G']
}

visited = []

def dfs(graph,node):
    global visited
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n)

    dfs(graph1,'A')
    print(visited)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'F']
```

Comment: First of all: don't use `global`s avoid them as much as possible!!

Comment: DFS is a *search*  algorithm, but there is *no target* defined you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks for the response..                                                                          visited = []

def dfs(graph,node,visited):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n,visited)

dfs(graph1,'A',visited)
print(visited)

Comment: I'm also not convinced that the output you show is generated by the data you show - I don't see where S, H and G come from? (But I could possibly be wrong here)

Comment: Hi Willem, if you checkout the link http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/ there a sample code for the DFS is given but If I change the graph as given in youtube tutorial  "https://youtu.be/iaBEKo5sM7w" I am not getting the result as mentioned. So I thought of writing my own version based on the tutorial.

Comment: Expected output doesn't match your test case. The algorithm looks OK to me.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for noticing, I had pasted wrong input which I fixed now

Answer (score 19):

I think you have an indentation problem there. Assuming your code looks like this:

```
graph1 = {
    'A' : ['B','S'],
    'B' : ['A'],
    'C' : ['D','E','F','S'],
    'D' : ['C'],
    'E' : ['C','H'],
    'F' : ['C','G'],
    'G' : ['F','S'],
    'H' : ['E','G'],
    'S' : ['A','C','G']
}

visited = []

def dfs(graph,node):
    global visited
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n)

dfs(graph1,'A')
print(visited)
```

I would say a couple of things:

- Avoid globals if you can
- Instead of a list for visited, use a set

plus:

- This will not work for forests but I assume you already know that
- It will fail if you reference a node that does not exist.

---

Updated code:

```
graph1 = {
    'A' : ['B','S'],
    'B' : ['A'],
    'C' : ['D','E','F','S'],
    'D' : ['C'],
    'E' : ['C','H'],
    'F' : ['C','G'],
    'G' : ['F','S'],
    'H' : ['E','G'],
    'S' : ['A','C','G']
}

def dfs(graph, node, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n, visited)
    return visited

visited = dfs(graph1,'A', [])
print(visited)
```

Comment: Should the updated code contain the variable `visited` as `dict` or `list`?

Comment: @Sudarshan since it says ```visited.append(node)``` the variable visited is a list.

Comment: @Juan Leni or anyone listening: In the for loop of your code, how is variable n not stuck in values between 'B' and 'A' and how come it jumps to 'S' in the third iteration?

Comment: `visited` should be a set to reduce runtime by o(n)

Comment: making visited a bit vector reduces checks to O(1), but one could instead store for every vertex the adjacent vertices in sets and remove visited vertices directly from them.

Answer (score 13):

Without recursion:

```py
def dfs(graph, node):
    visited = set((node,))
    output = [node]
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack[-1]
        if node not in visited:
            output.append(node)
            visited.add(node)
        remove_from_stack = True
        for next_node in graph[node]:
            if next_node not in visited:
                stack.append(next_node)
                remove_from_stack = False
                break
        if remove_from_stack:
            stack.pop()
    return output

print (dfs(graph1, 'A'))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'F']
```

Comment: 1. Why `extend` instead of `append`? 2. Why is `visited` a list and not a set?

Comment: `append` is fine. I prefer to leave `visited` as it is so it can keeps track of the visit order

Comment: If it is a list, you lose `o(n)` in performance.

Comment: Also note that `next` is a reserved word in Python

Comment: agree, I added a variable output to keep the right visited order

Answer (score 5):

Here's an iterative (non-recursive) implementation of a DFS:

```
def dfs_iterative(graph, start_vertex):
    visited = set()
    traversal = []
    stack = [start_vertex]
    while len(stack) > 0:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            traversal.append(vertex)
            stack.extend(reversed(graph[vertex]))   # add vertex in the same order as visited
    return traversal

test_graph = {
    'A' : ['B','S'],
    'B' : ['A'],
    'C' : ['D','E','F','S'],
    'D' : ['C'],
    'E' : ['C','H'],
    'F' : ['C','G'],
    'G' : ['F','S'],
    'H' : ['E','G'],
    'S' : ['A','C','G']
}

print(dfs_iterative(test_graph, 'A'))
```

Output:

`['A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'F']`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def DFS(self,v,vertex):
        visited = [False]*vertex
        print(self. graph)
        # print(len(self.graph),"+++")
        self.DFSUtil(v,visited)

    def DFSUtil(self,v,visited):
        visited[v]=True
        print(v)

        for i in self.graph[v]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                # print(visited)
                self.DFSUtil(i,visited)
g= Graph()

vertex=7

g.addEdge(0,1)
g.addEdge(0,2)
g.addEdge(0,6)
g.addEdge(0,5)
g.addEdge(5,3)
g.addEdge(5,4)
g.addEdge(4,3)
g.addEdge(6,4)

g.DFS(0,vertex)
```

This is the modification for the above code because that doesn't work with in all cases.
We have to specify the number of vectors and then give edges manually.

Comment: which cases does the above code fail for?

Answer (score 0):

DFS implementation in Python

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def DFSUtil(self, v, visited):
        visited[v]=True
        print(v)

        for i in self.graph[v]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                self.DFSUtil(i, visited)

    def DFS(self):
        V = len(self.graph)

        visited = [False]*(V)

        for i in range(V):
            if visited[i] == False:
                self.DFSUtil(i, visited)

# Driver code
# Create a graph given in the above diagram
g = Graph()
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 0)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(3, 3)

print("Following is Depth First Traversal")
g.DFS()
```

Source :: [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/)

Comment: @AssafLivne why not? Would you mind to expand a bit on that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
         'C': ['A', 'F'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['B', 'F'],
         'F': ['C', 'E']}

   def dfs(s,d):
    def dfs_helper(s,d):
        if s == d:
            return True
        if  s in visited :
            return False
        visited.add(s)
        for c in graph[s]:
            dfs_helper(c,d)
        return False
    visited = set()
    return dfs_helper(s,d) 
dfs('A','E') ---- True
dfs('A','M') ---- False
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a more versatile algorithm, the one asked in the question works only for undirected graphs. But this hopefully works for both them. *Check it out*

```
graph1= {
'A' : ['B','S'],
'B' : [],
'C' : ['E','S'],
'D' : ['C'],
'E' : ['H'],
'F' : ['C'],
'G' : ['F','S'],
'H' : ['G'],
'S' : []
}
visited = []

def dfs_visit(graph, s):
    global visited
    for v in graph[s]:
        if v not in visited:
            visited.append(v)
            dfs_visit(graph, v)


def dfs(graph):
    global visited
    for v in [*graph]:
        if v not in visited:
            visited.append(v)
            dfs_visit(graph,v)

dfs(graph1)
print(visited)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def DFS(graph,pointer,visit):
          visit.add(pointer)
          print(pointer,end=' ')

    for travel in graph[pointer]-visit:
        if travel not in visit:
            DFS(graph,travel,visit)


graph={'0':set(['1','2','3']),'1':set(['0','2']),'2':set(['0','1','4']),'3':set(['0']),'4':set(['2'])}
visit=set()
print("DFS for graph: ",graph)
DFS(graph,'0',visit)
```

Output

```
DFS for graph:  {'0': {'1', '3', '2'}, '1': {'0', '2'}, '2': {'1', '0', '4'}, '3': {'0'}, '4': {'2'}}
0 1 2 4 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive implementation:

```
def dfs(G, u, visited=[]):
    """Recursion version for depth-first search (DFS).
    Args:
        G: a graph
        u: start
        visited: a list containing all visited nodes in G
    Return:
        visited
    """
    visited.append(u)
    for v in G[u]:
        if v not in visited:
            dfs(G, v, visited)
    return visited
```

An iterative implementation using a stack:

```
def dfs_iterative(G, u, visited=[]):
    stack = [u, ] #initialize
    while stack:
        u = stack.pop()
        if u not in visited:
            visited.append(u)
            stack.extend(reversed(G[u])) #reversed() is used as the same traversal as recursive DFS
    return visited
```

Answer (score -1):

very basic code ig

```
def dfs(arr,vertex):
    dfs=[]
    stack=[]

    stack.append(vertex)
    while len(stack)!=0:
        top=stack.pop()
        if top not in dfs:
            dfs.append(top)
    
        for i in arr[top]:
            if i  in dfs:
                continue
            stack.append(top)
            stack.append(i)
            break
        




    return dfs

print(dfs(arr,'A'))
```