# Traversing a map in Python with DFS

Tags: python, depth-first-search

Helo everyone! I want to do an algorithm in Python that will traverse a map with DFS. And the problem is that it will block after visiting some of the good parts and it will not traverse all the map. I am using pygame, but I will share only my dfs method:

```
ef moveDSF(self, detectedMap):
        if len(self.stack):
            current = self.stack.pop()
            if current not in self.visited:
                self.visited.append(current)
                self.x = current[0]
                self.y = current[1]
                # print(current, self.stack)
                for position in v:  # v = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]
                    new_x = self.x + position[0]
                    new_y = self.y + position[1]
                    if 0 < new_x < 19 and 0 < new_y < 19 and detectedMap.surface[new_x][new_y] == 0:
                        neighbour = (new_x, new_y)
                        self.stack.append(neighbour)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The map is represented as a 20x20 matrix. At the start, in the stack we will have only the initial value and visited will be an empty list. We go one step at a time in this algorithm because the while loop will be in the pygame part. "detectedMap.surface[new_x][new_y] == 0" checks if that point is a good one, 1 being for walls.

Comment: hi, perhaps this simpler version might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430309/depth-first-search-dfs-code-in-python/43869149

Comment: I want to do it in the iterative method